# ajax search that filters returned records

Tags: asp.net, ajax

hi i want to create an search that uses ajax.

here are the requirements

1)on initial page load return all search data
2)have textbox that when typed in filters out the none matching records

any good tutorials out there on this

forgot to mention i'm using the telerik controls, using radgrid to display the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the answer you are looking for but if you are going to return all the search data on the initial page load there should be no reason for another trip to the server to filter the results.  I would suggest that you use javascript to filter which results are show to the user.  Jquery might make this easier.  http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: I agree with using jQuery, and if your search data is tabular, I'd recommend something like this jQuery plugin (http://www.datatables.net/), which has search built-in.